# Adding a storyboard reference to a TabBarController in Storyboard

Tags: storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, ios9, xcode7, storyboard-reference

In Xcode 7, when I add a reference to a TabBarController using relationship segue and refactor the view controller to a storyboard reference, the tab item goes back to the default title.  Is there a way to get around this?

For example, before Refactoring to Storyboard Reference, Tab 1 has a title of "My Item 1".

[image]

After refactoring to storyboard reference, the tab bar item reverts to Item 1 instead of My Item 1.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the first storyboard the tabBar item will have the default title and image. You should add a tabBar item for the viewController in the second storyboard. It will be used at runtime.